# Multiprocessing in python for loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to optimize my for loop which does the modeling by iterating over parameter to choose the best model.I have tried this via multiprocessing pool method.

```
for k in range(0, len(algo['mthod'])):          
                    start_time = time.time()
                    mv = mv(c.deepcopy(newob))
                    method = getattr(mv, algorithm['method'][k])
                    # results contains the predicted values for all the validation
                    # sets, the values returned is in the form of a dictionary
                    # numbered same as the validation dataframes
                    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
                    results = pool.starmap(method(algorithm['parameters'][k]))
                    #<<output>> format {'1':[results],'2':[results]}
                    Algo_time = time.time()-start_time
```

I am getting the error: **TypeError: starmap() missing 1 required positional argument: 'iterable'**

How to resolve this?

Comment: As specified in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap), the `starmap` method expects both a function and an iterable. Are you sure of what you want this function to do?

Comment: I want this method to iterate for every key [k] .
Is there any other way for this?